# SELECT DINAMICO Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

he tratado de hacer un select en HTML pero que sea llenado mediante la consulta a una base de datos, la BD tiene el nombre de las Areas disponibles y esas son las cuales deben de desplegarse ya intente con echo con selects dentro de un while,etc 
Esto es lo que llevo de codigo y marca un error si descomento el while

```
<div class="col-auto">
                    <select name="select" class="form-control">
                        <option value= 0>Seleccionar Area</option> 
                        <?php while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sResult)):?> 
                            <?php ECHO '<option value="'.$fila["ID"].'">'.$fila["AREA"].'</option>'; ?>


                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-info">Agregar Admin</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: usar la sentencia `while:` implica me parece que debas terminar la sentencia con `endwhile`

Comment: Puedes colocar el codigo de la sesion? y del query

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo 2 del bucle `while` https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php

Comment: No cierra el ciclo while tampoco si no estoy equivocado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece esta incompleto tu bucle y debería ser así:

```
<?php while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sResult)):?> 
     <?php echo '<option value="'.$fila["ID"].'">'.$fila["AREA"].'</option>'; ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

De la [doc de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php), esta sería la sintaxis a seguir

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10):
    echo $i;
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

- [Referencia a la doc de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php)

Comment: Gracias, tenias toda la razon ya se despliega como queria.. Gracias a todos los que comentaron :)

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas el `while` con `:` tenes que definir un `endwhile`. Asi quedaría:

```
  <div class="col-auto">
     <select name="select" class="form-control">
     <option value= 0>Seleccionar Area</option> 
     <?php 
          while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sResult)):
             ECHO '<option value="'.$fila["ID"].'">'.$fila["AREA"].'</option>';
          endwhile;
      ?>           
      </select>
  </div>
```

Otra opcion es

```
  <div class="col-auto">
     <select name="select" class="form-control">
     <option value= 0>Seleccionar Area</option> 
     <?php 
          while ( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sResult)) {
             ECHO '<option value="'.$fila["ID"].'">'.$fila["AREA"].'</option>';
          }
      ?>           
      </select>
  </div>
```